# Check for duplicates in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, duplicates

I have a json object:

```json
var object1 = [
                {"value1": "1", "value2": "2", "value3": "3",},
                {"value1": "1", "value2": "5", "value3": "7",},
                {"value1": "6", "value2": "9", "value3": "5",},
                {"value1": "6", "value2": "9", "value3": "5",}
]
```

Now I want to

- take each record out of that object
- and check how many times exact copy of that record is appearing in that object?

If it is only 1 copy do something and if it is more than 2 do something else. There are few answers on JSON duplicates but they target specific value not full record.

So I will take the record:

```json
{ "value1": "1", "value2": "2", "value3": "3",}
```

and compare it against `object1`. The above record will return 1 as there is only 1 copy inside `object1`

For Future use. Given these records

```js
var asset = [
    { value1: "1", value2: "2", value3: "3" },
    { value1: "1", value2: "5", value3: "7" },
    { value1: "6", value2: "9", value3: "5" },
    { value1: "6", value2: "9", value3: "5" }
];
```

This code can be used to find duplicates:

```js
function countEqual(oo, pp) {
    var count = 0;
    oo.forEach(function (el) {
        var i, equal = true;
        for (i in el) {
            equal = equal && el[i] === pp[i];
        }
        equal && count++;
    });
    return count;
}

var cleaned = [];

asset.forEach(function (itm) {
    var unique = true;
    cleaned.forEach(function (itm2) {
        if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
    });
    if (unique) cleaned.push(itm);
});

for (var i = 0; i < cleaned.length; i++) {
    if (countEqual(asset, cleaned[i]) === 1) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    else {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you consider as `duplicate`?

Comment: 1) That's not JSON. 2) you can't have duplicate keys in JavaScript objects. The end result of your assignment is that each object in `object1` will have one `value2` key.

Comment: Sorry yeah I wrote bad example I removed the keys

Comment: Also, that's not an object, it's an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: value1 compares to value 1? and 2 to 2 and 3 to 3? How should look the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var asset = [
    { value1: "1", value2: "2", value3: "3" },
    { value1: "1", value2: "5", value3: "7" },
    { value1: "6", value2: "9", value3: "5" },
    { value1: "6", value2: "9", value3: "5" }
];

function countEqual(oo, pp) {
    var count = 0;
    oo.forEach(function (el) {
        var i, equal = true;
        for (i in el) {
            equal = equal && el[i] === pp[i];
        }
        equal && count++;
    });
    return count;
}
console.log(countEqual(asset, { value1: "1", value2: "1", value3: "2" })); // 0
console.log(countEqual(asset, { value1: "1", value2: "2", value3: "3" })); // 1
console.log(countEqual(asset, { value1: "6", value2: "9", value3: "5" })); // 2
```

Comment: Yes that worked fine. From my side I had to clean up "asset" object to contain only unique values. Then, use for loop on the new unique array and apply it to your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a function that will count the number of occurrences of an object in an array, the following code should help you (this assumes that the properties in your objects will always follow the same order. If you aren't sure about that you should use a proper equality check function):

```
var nbOcc = function (needle, haystack) {
  return haystack.filter(function (record) {
    return JSON.stringify(needle) === JSON.stringify(record);
  }).length;
};

console.log(nbOcc({
  "value1": "1",
  "value2": "2",
  "value3": "3",
}, object1)); // 1

console.log(nbOcc({
  "value1": "6",
  "value2": "9",
  "value3": "5",
}, object1)); // 2
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/44jpyfnf/)